# Bind setInterval() to a jQuery element

Tags: javascript, jquery, setinterval

I have a toast notification system which displays a notification for 10 seconds before fading out. I want to add a functionality that pauses the countdown for fading out when the notification is hovered, and resumes when no longer hovering.

I'm trying to use the `setInterval()` function to do this, but I'm unsure how to later pause (clear) this interval. I know I can bind the setInterval to a variable, but **these notifications are created dynamically, so I cannot bind them to a single variable.**

In the example below, I store the `setInterval()` in a variable named `???`, I would ideally bind this interval using the jQuery element (`$(this)`) as a variable so it's always unique, and can easily be cleared by passing the same jQuery element through the `clearInterval()` function.

Is there any way of doing this, or am I going about building this system all wrong?

```
// Start notification countdown
$.countDownNotification = function(notification) {
    // IMPORTANT: Store the setInterval in a element-specific variable?
    var ??? = setInterval( function() {
        // Counts down from remaining seconds
        var remaining = notification.attr('data-timer') + 1 - 1;

        // Stores remaining seconds in data-attribute
        notification.attr('data-timer', remaining);

        // Remove notification when timer is on 0
        if ( remaining == 0 ) {
            notification.remove();
        }
    }, 1000);
}

// Pause on hover
$('.notification').on('mouseenter', function(e) {
    // IMPORTANT: Clear the elemnt-specific interval
    clearInterval(???);
});

// Resume when hover ends
$('.notification').on('mouseleave', function(e) {
    var notification = $(this)

    $.countDownNotification(notification);
});
```

Comment: Use `.data()` instead of `.attr()`. This would also get rid of the `+ 1 - 1` to make it a number again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can store the interval on the notification via `.data()`.

```
notification.data('int', setInterval(...
```

Then, in the event callbacks you can reference the interval via

```
$(this).data('int')
```

Also, note + 1 - 1 doesn't do anything meaningful.

Answer (score 1):

Consider declaring a global variable.

```
// Start notification countdown
$.countDownNotification = function(notification) {
    // IMPORTANT: Store the setInterval in a element-specific variable?
    timer = setInterval( function() {
        // Counts down from 10 and stores new value in data-attribute
        notification.attr('data-timer', notification.attr('data-timer') - 1);
    }, 1000);

    // Remove notification when timer is on 0
    if ( newRemaining == 0 ) {
        notification.remove();
    }
}

// `false` means no timer has been set
var timer = false;

// Pause on hover
$('.notification').on('mouseenter', function(e) {
    // IMPORTANT: Clear the elemnt-specific interval
    clearInterval( timer );
});

// Resume when hover ends
$('.notification').on('mouseleave', function(e) {
    var notification = $(this)

    $.countDownNotification(notification);
});
```

Another way to not set a global object is to return `setInterval()` by `.countDownNotification`.

```
// Start notification countdown
$.countDownNotification = function(notification) {
    // IMPORTANT: Store the setInterval in a element-specific variable?
    var id = setInterval( function() {
        // Counts down from 10 and stores new value in data-attribute
        notification.attr('data-timer', notification.attr('data-timer') - 1);
    }, 1000);

    // Remove notification when timer is on 0
    if ( newRemaining == 0 ) {
        notification.remove();
    }

    return id;

}

( function() {

    // `false` means no timer has been set
    var timer = false;

    // Pause on hover
    $('.notification').on('mouseenter', function(e) {
        // IMPORTANT: Clear the elemnt-specific interval
        clearInterval( timer );
    });

    // Resume when hover ends
    $('.notification').on('mouseleave', function(e) {
        var notification = $(this)

        timer = $.countDownNotification(notification);
    });

})();
```

Comment: Hi, this would not work as multiple notifications can be on screen at the same time, with multiple countdowns going on. If I understand correctly, using a global `timer` variable would clear all the notifications at the same time.

Comment: @Swen Hey <3.
Well, that was the concept, not the actual production code. In the case to achieve what you've explained, you need to set an ID for each `.notification` element on your page. Then when a user fires `mouseleave`, you can retrieve it using `$( this ).attr( 'data-timer-id' )` for example. and `.clearInterval( timer[ dataTimerID] )` would do the job for you.

Comment: That would work! But using the jQuery `data` attribute was the most convenient for my use case. Still upvoted though :)

Comment: @Swen While they were sharing the same idea, and despite my answer submitted sooner, I think *utkanos* were right on the point. He deserves that green tick more. That's fine. <3